# What are some adjectives that are usually used without a subject or verb in response to something, similar to "agreed"?

Tags: word-request, ellipsis, informal-language

Consider the following example:

> **A:**  How about I do the dishes and you make dinner?
> **B:** *Agreed*.

Could you give me other examples for adjectives that are usually used in this way?

Comment: Almost any! Q: "What colour was that car?" A: "Red." However 'agreed' can very often be used in a complete sentence: "I was waiting at the agreed meeting point."

Comment: And why must it be an adjective? "Agreed" is a verb, as well. The reply is more likely short for, "[I've] agreed". Verbs are sometimes used without subject (i.e., subject understood). "Go!" is the shortest English sentence.